# Change Windows shell in Jenkins (from Cygwin to Git Bash/msys)

Tags: windows, bash, jenkins, cygwin, msysgit

I have a Windows 7 and a Windows Server 2012 slave with the Jenkins agent and Cygwin already set up. I want to avoid Cygwin and just use the Git Bash shell that comes with Git for Windows (I think it's called msysgit). So I renamed `C:\cygwin64` to `C:\cygwin64.bak`, removed `C:\cygwin64\bin` from the path, and rebooted.

The Windows 2012 box now works fine, (Unix) shell scripts run, `$OSTYPE = msys`, and `uname = MSYS_NT-6.3` (indicating that the Git Bash shell is running).

The Windows 7 box won't run anything, and gives the following error:

> Building remotely on win7 in workspace C:\Users\Jenkins\workspace\TEST
>   [win7] $ sh -xe C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson5047939025129374618.sh
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>   FATAL: command execution failed
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Users\Jenkins\workspace\TEST"): CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
>                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)

So my question is, how do I configure Jenkins to use `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`, or `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` to run shell scripts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've worked it out. Jenkins will simply pick the first sh.exe in the path. Git Bash has an exe at `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, so if you add that to the beginning of your path it will be picked up by Jenkins.

You have to restart your slave's connection with Jenkins after making this change, otherwise the Path won't propagate. If you're using the Java Web Start, just close the java window and relaunch it.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` also has a sh.exe in it.  Any reason not to use that?

Comment: @BitwiseMan No idea. Is that a symlink?

Comment: Symlink on windows? Doubt it.  :)  Either way, I'm just wondered if you'd tried it with the shorter path.

Comment: So I just had a look on a machine, and both `bash.exe` and `sh.exe` in `Git\bin`are 32kb, so I suspect they're just pointers to the real location. I do think `Git\bin` is a better default, that seems like the path you're supposed to use. I tried another machine with an older Git installation (in `Program Files (x86)`) and `\usr\bin` wasn't actually there.

Comment: You can create symlinks in Windows with `mklink`. (bonus information nugget)

Comment: Jenkins requires `nohup` when using sh as part of Pipeline builds (see [JENKINS-33708](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33708)) so I had to use `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` in the PATH in order for it work, since `nohup.exe` is there.

Comment: Right @Nick. Ref: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33708 

I switched to cygwin & just configured windows path env. it worked like charm

Comment: I had to add both C:\Program Files\Git\bin *and* C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to system env vars to get this to work, and also reboot the machine (just restarting the java web start didn't do it)

Answer (score 11):

If you have only Windows agents and they all the have Git for Windows installed to the same location you can set the shell executable for all agents in the Jenkins System Configuration.

Go to **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure System**, scroll down to **Shell** and set the **Shell executable** to point to whatever shell you want to start with the *Execute shell* build step.

Here's an example how to set the shell which is installed with Git for Windows:

[image: Jenkins shell configuration]

Note: This won't work if you have a mixture of Windows and non-Windows agents ([JENKINS-38211](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38211)). It will cause similar issues if you have Windows agents where `sh.exe` is installed to different locations (such as a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit Windows using the default install location for those platforms). Use this only when your environment contains only identically configured Windows nodes.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's really interesting. Do you know what that setting applies to? It's a global setting on the master machine, so I'm unclear whether it just applies to the master or to all the slaves.

Comment: The global setting seems to apply to all slaves too, @gibfahn. I have three slaves, I installed Git for Windows on all of them (and master) and set the **Shell executable** to point to `sh.exe`. Now I can run jobs with _Execute shell_ build steps on all slaves.

Comment: So if you run a jenkins job that echoes the default windows path on the machines does that not include `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`?

Comment: No, the path has only `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` (even on the slaves). I configured the *Shell executable* with full path to Git's `sh.exe`.

Comment: Okay great, sounds like that would work in any deployment as long as you always have the shell in the same place (and you want to use the same shell on all machines). Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @apa64 - This will break if you have linux machines that don't have sh.exe, right?

Comment: @BitwiseMan Yeah, I'd expect it to break, this works properly in Win-only environment. If you could configure the shell executable per slave you could have a mixed environment but it can't be done in Jenkins v. 1.651.3 (not from the UI at least).

Comment: @apa64 - I submitted an edit to highlight this problems with this method.

Comment: And yes - this DOES break in mixed-OS-slave env (just added the first linux slave here...). It's best to add Git usr/bin to the PATH on Windows slaves as instructed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Install git-bash**

Ensure the Git\bin folder (i.e.: C:\Program Files\Git\bin) is in the global search path, in order for Jenkins to find sh.exe

to update path in windows use following command

setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin"

or have a look here https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/

**to make nohup available for Jenkins**

- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\nohup.exe" "C:\Program
  Files\git\usr\bin\nohup.exe"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\msys-2.0.dll" "C:\Program
  Files\git\usr\bin\msys-2.0.dll"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\msys-iconv-2.dll" "C:\Program
  Files\git\usr\bin\msys-iconv-2.dll"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\msys-intl-8.dll" "C:\Program
  Files\git\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll"

That's it now you can run shell commands

**Have fun**

Comment: This answer is better than the next one, because it allows to run both Windows batch and Unix shell scripts in your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: I'm still having an issue with Jenkins seeing the bash command, even after restarting there seems to be an issue for me. **FATAL: Cannot run program "bash":**

Answer (score 0):

on the node agent configuration:
check the Tool  Locations,
add the home path of git,
for e.g C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
and save
reconnect the client.it will work