# How to display bash script execution on Jenkins Console from Cygwin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cygwin

Calling the below bash script from Jenkins pipeline but I don't see the script execution on Jenkins console, can someone please advise how to display execution on jenkins console, bash script execution which is running on cygwin(on windows agent) 
 bat'call D:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe  /usr/bin/bash -lic \"/home/test.sh\" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to accomplish this is to go to "Manage Jenkins", "Configure System", and change the "Shell executable" parameter to your cygwin bash address. As your example shows, something like D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe. Then, on the job configuration, you can select on "Build", "Execute Shell". You can paste your test.sh script content in there. Like this:

[image: Jenkins execute shell example]

With this configuration, Jenkins will run whatever you pasted in the "Execute shell" screen using the bash.exe address you provided in the configuration. I believe this is the most seamless way to execute shell scripts on Jenkins running on windows. The output looks almost Linux native:

[image]

Comment: I Cannot add shell executable on Jenkins main configuration page as we have different agents are configured and I don't see particularly for windows agent slave to configure the cygwin bash executable. Please advise.

Comment: This configuration is global. If you install Cygwin on the nodes as well in the master, just make sure they are all installed in the same path. What I do is to always leave it at the default C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe. Alternatively, you can create a system environment variable with the Cygwin bin path on each node, and use as the "Shell executable" path something like %CYGWIN_PATH%\bin\bash.exe

Comment: added D:\cygwin64\bin\ to system variable path on windows agent server and still I need to add the D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe on Jenkins configure system on global configuration?

Comment: If you added D:\cygwin64\bin\ to the system environment variable, then the "Shell executable" path can be just bash.exe. Jenkins will probably find it by itself given the environment path, but I found its always better to explicitly declare it.

Comment: ok, will update D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe on Jenkins main configuration page on shell executable field.Thanks.

Comment: I see the below article that if we have different agents(windows and non windows then adding shell executable for windows won't work.Please advise.                          This won't work if you have a mixture of Windows and non-Windows agents (JENKINS-38211). It will cause similar issues if you have Windows agents where sh.exe is installed to different locations (such as a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit Windows using the default install location for those platforms). Use this only when your environment contains only identically configured Windows nodes.

Comment: Please see below link for above  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043665/change-windows-shell-in-jenkins-from-cygwin-to-git-bash-msys